# Solo.call and solo.endcall usage in android testing using robotium

Tags: robotium

I am quite new android testing. Iam using robotium for testing application. I want to know the usage of the CALL and ENDCALL fields .I am not able to end call using the field.
Please suggest me on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two have been removed from Robotium 2.0 just because of all the problems that users have experienced with them. Due to security reasons one is not allowed to interact with other applications if they do not have the same certificate singing and are not defined in the AndroidManifest.xml of the test project. What those two try to do is to start and control the contacts application. Due to security reasons that introduces problems. My advice would be to update to Robotium 2.0 and stop trying to use them.

/Renas